# RPi 3 connects to Wi-Fi and has internet access, but not visible in MS Explorer

Tags: networking

I have a RPi 3 that's running Libreelec and up until two days ago, it never had an issue appearing in MS Explorer under Network and Homegroup. It is connected to the Wi-Fi and I can actually see/transfer files to the Pi from my computer using a tool like Advanced IP Scanner, which opens in an explorer window using the IP address.

Why doesn't Windows recognize the Pi as a networked device? I did a search of my internet history to make sure I didn't do anything to alter the network or the Pi, but it looks like the only thing I did was connect a new Steam Link.

How can I make the Pi visible again?

Answer (score 1):

You need mDNS service(s) running. It’s called various things; bonjour, rendezvous, whatever. Try running `netstat -tnlp` as root, and see if port 5353/udp is open. It’s multicast-DNS for discovery and identification of resources on the local network. Samba should be able to handle it, but if it doesn’t, use `apt search mdns` and see what you can work with. Of course, look for mDNS related settings in /etc/samba/ ...

Since it has worked, you either changed something, or (equally likely) the service has just stopped working. Perhaps after an update, perhaps for no apparent reason. Check in /etc for relevant configurations, see the output of `systemctl —status-all` (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't have the same file system as rasbian/linux.
So You have  to mount a samba server
See the tutorial here:
[RPI-Win](https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-share-a-folder-with-a-windows-computer-from-a-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: I don't think (lack of) Samba is the issue, as the first paragraph suggests samba is running on the Pi (`I can actually see/transfer files to the Pi from my computer`) - the issue is visibility of the Pi in microsoft windows "network" section in Explorer